# How do I call the bitbucket api through the browser?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I used to call the api's through the Bitbucket api browser. Now that it is not available anymore, how do I call the api's?

Answer (score 0):

There is detailed documentation here for Bitbucket cloud.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-bitbucket-cloud-rest-apis-222724129.html

You can try cloud APIs from any browser very much similar to Bitbucket Server APIs. For ex https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/tutorials/tutorials.bitbucket.org